# Items are aligned right to left instead left to right

Tags: android, css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

The problem: items are aligned from right to left instead of left to right ( When debugging with a USB cable )

In the emulator ( 3 diff devices checked [ Android ] ) its normal ( left to right), but when connecting my phone with USB to the computer and debug, I see the elements aligned from right to left. when doing flexDirection: 'row' , of course.

Anyone have any idea why does it happen?

**Example:**

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row',flex: 1 }}>
  <Text style={{ flex: 1 }}> one </Text>
  <Text style={{ flex: 1 }}> two </Text>
  <Text style={{ flex: 1 }}> three </Text>
</View>
```

**In the emulator - >**

one two three

**In my phones - >**

three two one

this also happens if I remove the flex: 1.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 4):

This probably due to the fact that the main language in your android device is an "RTL language", such as Arabic, Persian or Hebrew.
Since Android 4, the device automatically reverses the layout of the page to support RTL languages and react-native supports this feature.
However, if you want to disable it, you can go to "./android/app/src/main" and find AndroidManifest.xml and in the

```
<Application .... />
```

section add the following line:

```
android:supportsRtl="true"
```

so that the final result will be something like below:

```
<application 

    .
    .
    .
    android:supportsRtl="false"

    .
    .
    .
/>
```

Afterwards (as you have changed an android related file) you need to rebuild your project by writing the following line in the command line (in the project folder):

```
react-native run-android
```